# /* @flow strict */ On all source files

Tags: javascript, flowtype

With `all=true` i can make flow check all files. 
How do i expand this to strictly checking all files?

My current .flowconfig:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*

[libs]
flow-typed

[options]
all=true
module.use_strict=true

[strict]
nonstrict-import
unclear-type
unsafe-getters-setters
untyped-import
untyped-type-import
```

The last strict part is not applied unless i type `/* @flow strict */` in files. I want to avoid adding a comment to all files if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question got answered on github:

> As far as I understand strict, it's actually just setting all of the lints in [strict] to error. Try changing the [strict] section to [lints] and add =error to the end of each line. So:
>
> [lints]
>
> nonstrict-import=error
>
> unclear-type=error
>
> unsafe-getters-setters=error
>
> untyped-import=error
>
> untyped-type-import=error
>
> That should set all of these lints as errors when flow type checks.
> Let me know if this isn't sufficient.

I'll just link the answer here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6967

Unfortunately I have not had time to test the solution provided, maybe someone else can confirm?